# jQuery изменение динамических элементов

Tags: jquery

Есть ссылки в которые данные подгружаются из БД:

```
@foreach ($classes as $class)
  <i class="fa fa-2x pt-2 blue-text ico_edit{{ $class->id }}">&#x{{ $class->ico->code}}</i>
  <a class="inputlabel-editNews ico_edit{{ $class->id}} mb-0 mt-2" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#IconsModal">
 <div class="m-2 pt-2" ">
 Изменить
 </div>
 </a>

@endforeach
```

При клике на ссылку открывается модальное окно со списком иконок, в котором при выборе иконки она должна замениться в ссылке. как это правильно реализовать?
Сейчас у меня сделано так:

```
@foreach ($classes as $class)
jQuery(document).on('click','#icoedit-choose',function(e){
        var ico_code = $(this).find('.ico-code').text();
        $('i.ico_edit{{ $class->id }}').html(ico_code);
    });
 @endforeach
```

и при клике по иконке меняется иконка во всех ссылках, а надо чтобы менялась иконка в конкретной ссылке...

```
 <form class="tr" role="form" id="form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id_edit" id="id_edit"  value="">
<div class="td border align-middle p-2 text-center ico_edit">
<i class="fa fa-2x pt-2 blue-text ico_edit">тут иконка</i>
<a class="inputlabel-editNews ico_edit mb-0 mt-2" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#IconsModal">
<div class="row justify-content-center m-2 pt-2" value="">
<i class="fas fa-pen pr-1 blue-text"></i>Изменить
</div>
</a>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="ico_edit" id="ico_edit"  value="">
```

Comment: во-первых уберите навешивание обработчика в цикле. во вторых вам тут в целом `on` не нужен. При клике в ссылку перед открытие модального окна сохраните указатель  на эту ссылку,  или ee id. При закрытии модального окна возьмие сохраненную ссылку, и измените в ней класс.

Comment: `on` нужен потому что  `#icoedit-choose` создается при клике по ссылке другой и просто клик не работает. Если обработчик делаю вне цикла то скрипт не понимает такие конструкции `ico_edit{{ $class->id }}`. С указанием ид при открытие и закрытие модалки пробывал и все равно иконки меняет во всех ссылках....

Comment: убрать из цикла значит что вам нужен всего один общий обработчик, который будет в коде у себя понимать, на что кликнули (`e.relatedTarget`), а при закрытии окна эти сведения будут использованы. Не надо вешать свой обработчик на каждую ссылку.

Comment: я и сам прекрасно понимаю что один обработчик хорошо, но как сделать на его на динамически созданные ссылки всю голову сломал...

Comment: приведите лучше пример готовой верстки без пхп, чтобы из нее можно было сниппет сделать.

Comment: Не совсем понял что нужно, но убрал пхп и оставил только верстку, выше закинул

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы хотите сделать что-то типо такого..

```js
$('.icon-list').on('click', '.icon-item', function(){
  let icon = $(this).find('i').attr('class');
  $('.icon-view').find('i').attr('class', icon);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css');

i {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

i::before {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-view {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-list {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icon-list::after {  
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.icon-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-item:hover {
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-item i {
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon-view">
  <i></i>
</div>

<div class="icon-list">
  <div class="icon-item">
    <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item">
    <i class="fas fa-ad"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item">
    <i class="fab fa-alipay"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item">
    <i class="fas fa-angry"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Т.е. при выборе из списка менять иконку.

Т.к. вы используете FontAwesome, я предлагаю менять не саму иконку (`<i class="***"></i>`), а именно класс (пример выше).

---

```js
$('.icon-list').on('click', '.icon-item', function(){
  let icon = $(this).find('i').attr('class'),
      iconClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  $('.icon-view.'+iconClass).find('i').attr('class', icon);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css');

i {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

i::before {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.icon-viewer {
  display: block;
}

.icon-view {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-view:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.icon-list {
  max-width: 275px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icon-list::after, .icon-viewer::after {  
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.icon-item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-item i {
  margin: -1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.icon-view.one-view {
  background: gray;
}

.icon-view.two-view {
  background: red;
}

.icon-view.three-view {
  background: blue;
}

.icon-item.one-view {
  color: gray;
}

.icon-item.two-view {
  color: red;
}

.icon-item.three-view {
  color: blue;
}

.icon-item.one-view:hover {
  background: gray;
}

.icon-item.two-view:hover {
  background: red;
}

.icon-item.three-view:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.icon-item:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon-viewer">
  <div class="icon-view one-view">
    <i></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-view two-view">
    <i></i>
  </div>

  <div class="icon-view three-view">
    <i></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="icon-list">
  <div class="icon-item one-view">
    <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item two-view">
    <i class="fas fa-ad"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item three-view">
    <i class="fab fa-alipay"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item one-view">
    <i class="fas fa-angry"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item three-view">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item one-view">
    <i class="fab fa-aviato"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item two-view">
    <i class="fas fa-band-aid"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item three-view">
    <i class="fas fa-battery-full"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item two-view">
    <i class="fab fa-behance-square"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item one-view">
    <i class="fas fa-birthday-cake"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item two-view">
    <i class="fas fa-bone"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item three-view">
    <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item one-view">
    <i class="fas fa-chess"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item three-view">
    <i class="fas fa-car-side"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-item one-view">
    <i class="fas fa-box"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает, ничего не происходит...

Comment: Скиньте код не в цикле, а который уже на html, хотя бы самой вёрстки

Comment: Не совсем понял что нужно, но убрал пхп и оставил только верстку, выше закинул

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Имменно это я и хочу, и именно так у меня сейчас и работает, НО если классов `class="icon-view` будет два и более, как сделать чтобы иконка менялась именно в том классе. вот проблема моя в чем(

Comment: @BorsheC, дополнил ответ

Comment: Уже ближе)))) но  у меня нет списка из красных, синих и серых иконок)) . У меня список из 1500 тыс. иконок с одинаковым классом и около 200 динамических ссылок в которых нужно менять иконку. По этому я и присваивал ссылкам класс `class->id`...